# Spring @Scheduled is executing task twice when using annotations

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I have made task using Spring @Scheduled annotation, but for some reason it is executing task twice. My Spring Framework version is 3.0.2.

```
@Service
public class ReportService {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=1000 * 60 * 60* 24)
    @Transactional
    public void dailyReportTask()
    {
        ... code here ...
    }

}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">
    <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" />
    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1" />
    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"
        scheduler="taskScheduler" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you paste some of the relevant application context or other such configuration? Is there perhaps another scheduled task that's calling this one?

Answer (score 7):

it is happening because of context listener

Just remove

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

from `web.xml` it should work.

Comment: why it work twice to Spring Scheduler? I also remove context listener, It didn't work twice. But I want to know the reason.

Comment: is it safe to remove my `ContextLoaderListener` from web.xml ? to make this work

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and I eventually found out that the problem was occurring as a result of the beans being created in the `root context` as well as the `servlet context`.

So, to fix this, you need to separate the creation of the beans into the appropriate contexts.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850897/1646783) explains really well how to that and was what fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to this post: http://www.vodori.com/blog/spring3scheduler.html

> Spring 3.0.0 Release had a bug where
>   web apps with a task scheduler would
>   end up executing scheduled methods
>   twice. This has been resolved in
>   Spring 3.0.1.

There has been another bug reported which affects Version/s: 3.0.2
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7216

Which should be fixed in Version/s: 3.0.3.

Comment: I got the same problem and I use Spring 3.1.1.Release

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem recently and it was caused by my app being deployed twice in Tomcat by eclipse. The problem was that I had renamed my application in eclipse but the "wb-module deploy-name" specified in the "org.eclipse.wst.common.component" .settings file still had the old name.

In the tomcat manager, I could see that I had 2 apps running with different names.

Comment: Had the same problem because I had symlinked ROOT to my app folder and both were deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you actually running it? Your PC? Single server? 2 x load-balanced app servers?

Could be it's running on (a) your PC and (b) your server, so it just looks like it's running twice, if you see what I mean: it's correctly running once, just on two distinct locations.

Comment: Just running on my development machine ... it has only one istance running ... I run it from eclipse ...

Comment: Is it running on an app server on your machine, e.g. Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish, to which you deploy from Eclipse?  Or is it running as a standalone app?  Eclipse may be letting you run a 2nd app while a first one is still actually running.

Comment: Its Eclipse embedded tomcat 6 server. And Im usre I have just one instance running, i checked it from task manager.

Comment: Interesting.  If it was me, I would set up a standalone Tomcat 6 on my PC and deploy from Eclipse to that instead.  If the problem still manifests, at least you can be sure that's a code/application problem. I'd also maybe change the scheduling to run once per hour to see if it continues to run the new schedule twice even on that separate deployed instance

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any manual scheduler config in your configuration files (through Java/XML). I'ved the same problem, and I discover that my config was loading my scheduler class twice:

In Java:

```
package com.mywork.br.myschuedulerpackage;
{...}
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CTXDataImporterScheduler ctxDataImporterScheduler() {
        return new CTXDataImporterScheduler();
    }
}
```

In XML applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mywork.br.myschuedulerpackage" />
```

And in my scheduler class, I had @Component annotation thats was catch by the component scan and loaded a second time causing the @scheduler methods being executed twice.
I removed the Java config and then is working well now!

Answer (score 0):

To solve twice-working of `@Scheduled` method just delete `ContextLoaderListener` from you **web.xml** (if you use web.xml-based application):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Or** if you use `WebApplicationInitializer`-based application just delete a string that adds ContextLoaderListener:

```
package com.dropbox.shortener.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class DropboxShortenerWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        // (!) Delete the next string
        // container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(WebConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        setupCharEncodingFilter(container);
    }

    private void setupCharEncodingFilter(ServletContext container) {
        container.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

        FilterRegistration charEncodingFilterReg = container.addFilter("CharacterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
        charEncodingFilterReg.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        charEncodingFilterReg.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        charEncodingFilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) on your bean

Answer (score 0):

```
Disabling below will work.
 <!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener> -->
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution I would suggest is to do component scat like this

-In application context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.cde.dao" />
```

In yourservlet-servlet.xml

```
<!-- package that had all the @Controller classes -->
```

I this way the servlet is only loaded if the web.xml is loaded
 Similar can be done for task