# spring web, security + web.xml + mvc dispatcher + Bean is created twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the Web.xml as below:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/secure/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

[Edit]

After I added the spring security, then I get the error!

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found:  no
>   ContextLoaderListener registered?

then I added

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

then it seems working fine, but then 
1) The problem is the bean are created twice!

if I only remove that:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

but leave the `<listener>` then the web application doesn't run at all

[Extra]

The full Web.xml is below:

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

here is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ge.wtracker"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Java Persistence API config-->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.ge.wtracker.repository"/>

    <!--JPA and Database Config-->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPersistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Spring Security-->
    <security:http create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="customRestFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </security:http>
    <!-- Configures the authentication entry point that returns HTTP status code 401 -->
    <bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.ge.wtracker.web.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="Not Authorized" />
    </bean>
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="restAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!--The customRestFilter responsibles for retrieving and manipulating any request data to pass to the authentication
        provider to authenticate.-->
    <bean id="customRestFilter" class="com.ge.wtracker.web.security.RestSecurityFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <constructor-arg name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="restAuthenticationProvider" class="com.ge.wtracker.web.security.RestAuthenticationProvider" />

</beans>
```

Comment: If you leave the listener it doesn't run specifying which error? No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Comment: no error, only return Response code: 404
Response message: Not Found

Comment: Please show evidence that the bean is created twice. Post your logs.

Comment: I run in dubug mode, and have my break point inside of my "RestSecurityFilter" constructor, the class which extends GenericFilterBean. It runs twice if I have the <listener> and <context-param> in the web.xml, if I remove those, it exactly runs it once!

Answer (score 39):

During the servlet container lifecycle, the container first initializes the `ServletContextListener`, then the `Filter` and `Servlet` instances.

A Spring Web application typically loads two contexts: the root context and the dispatcher servlet context. The `ContextLoaderListener` class is a `ServletContextListener` which loads the application (or root) context. It identifies the file to load either through the `context-param` with the name `contextConfigLocation` as given in the web.xml like below

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

or, by default, by looking for a file at `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. Since you've specified `/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` as the `contextConfigLocation`, that context will be loaded.

Once this is done, the container initializes the `DispatcherServlet`, which also loads a context. It identifies the file load either through an `init-param` element with the name `contextConfigLocation` as given in the web.xml below

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/some-random-location.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

or, by default, by looking for a file at `/WEB-INF/name-of-your-servlet-servlet.xml`. In other words, it takes the value of the `<servlet-name>` element and appends `-servlet.xml` to it and looks for it in `WEB-INF`.

Since you haven't specified an `init-param` with name `contextConfigLocation`, the `DispatcherServlet` loads the context file at `/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`, since its name is `mvc-dispatcher`. The context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` has access to the beans loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`, that's why we call that the root context (and the others children).

All this to say that both your `ContextLoaderListener` and your `DispatcherServlet` are creating their own copy of an `ApplicationContext` by each loading a `XmlWebApplicationContext` from the same file at `/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Identify what beans or configuration you think should be available to the whole application and put them in the file that will be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. Identify the beans or configuration you think should be available to the `DispatcherServlet` and put them in its context file.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s02.html

> The framework will, on initialization of a DispatcherServlet, look for
>   a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of
>   your web application and create the beans defined there (overriding
>   the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global
>   scope).

So you can remove the context-param:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC then create a new any-name.xml and place context specific beans like 
Spring-security.xml and  for your security  bean to load.

New xml will be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
<task:annotation-driven/> 
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.
config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="location" value=""/>
    <property name="locations">
           <list>
               <value>/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties</value>
           </list>
        </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>            
</bean>
</beans>
```

and now include this in web.xml

```
  <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>  
      /WEB-INF/login-security.xml,
      /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
   </param-value>
 </context-param>
```

hope this will help you.