# How to dump autowired spring beans to a xml configuration file?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using the @Autowired annotation with spring-mvc and spring-security, it works, but the webapp start very slow, about 1 munute every time, because the spring-mvc and  spring-security scan twice all autowired classes and the total count of classes about 500.
Are there any suggestions to speed up the scan time? or the static xml configuration is better?

in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    ....
```

in rest-sevlet.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycomp" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:interceptors>
    ....
    </mvc:interceptors>
<import resource="classes/config/applicationContext-security-base.xml"/>
<import resource="classes/config/applicationContext-security.xml"/>

<import resource="classes/config/spring-aop.xml"/>
<!-- i18n --> 
<import resource="classes/config/spring-locale.xml"/>
```

Comment: Why would the classes be scanned twice?! Spring Security only scans defined beans (i.e. `@Components` in the context). component-scan scans the classpath for beans. If that is wrongly configured you can have duplicate beans. And next to that why is the startup-time a problem? Anyway post some configuration and your web.xml.

Comment: Use a profiler to see where the time is going. Spring is usually quick to start up, but some of your beans might take time (eg Hibernate?)

Comment: Scan twice it coused by spring-mvc sevlet (rest-servlet) and spring-security filter, I think. Both they are need a separated spring-context.

Comment: Just like the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826228/spring-web-xml-bean-is-created-twice-with?rq=1)there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't load your configuration twice. Currently both the `ContextLoaderListener` as well as the `DispatcherServlet` load the same configuration files. Result duplicate bean instances, duplicate scanning (and next to that in the future memory problems, weird transaction problems etc.).

Your configuration needs to be split. Your `ContextLoaderListener` should **only load things that are general** to your application (services, repositories, datasources etc.). The DispatcherServlet in turn should contain/load **only web related** things like `(@)Controllers`, `ViewResolvers`, `View`s, mvc configuration etc.

Also beware of component-scanning and don't fall into the trap everyone does. If you add the **same** comonent-scan to each configuration file this will result in bean duplication (ever bean is instantiated twice). So make sure that your `ContextLoaderListener' scans for everything but controllers and that your`DispatcherServlet` scans only for web related content (controllers for instance).