# Spring @Scheduled task runs twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, scheduled-tasks

I am creating an `@Scheduled` task to run every 5 seconds. As has been a problem in other questions, my task is running twice!

I have looked at other questions, and read the applicable documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled), but I have not been able to figure out the problem.

I know that **two seperate** instances of my `@Scheduled` class are getting instantiated when I start my tomcat server. I have also figured out when they are instantiated in reference to my log file.

One associated with this log line :

> INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

and another with this log line:

> INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'servlet'

Here is the spring config file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="web.controllers"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="services"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="scheduled"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/application.properties"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<task:annotation-driven />
```

And my simple java class:

```
package scheduled;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Notifier {

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void notifyUsersOfBidItems() {
    try {
        System.out.println(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Also, I am using Spring 4.

EDIT: `Adding web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/notFound</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error/notFound</location>
</error-page>


<error-page>
    <location>/error/internal</location>
</error-page>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the spring mvc framework and debugged the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is caused by same config file being loaded twice in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config.xml</param-value> <!-- FIRST -->
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config.xml</param-value> <!-- SECOND -->
</context-param>
```

EDIT
To fix it:

Create another file servlet-servlet.xml (this will be picked up by the ServletDispatcher config by default since it matches the file by servlet name)
The file will contain this:

```
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="web.controllers"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
</beans>
```

Modify the original file (spring-config.xml):

```
<beans>
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="services"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="scheduled"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/application.properties"/>
</beans>
```

Modify your web xml servlet config to following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: I thought that might be the error as well, but I tried removing each one and both threw different errors. Do u know how to only define it once?

Comment: see the edited answer on how to do it.There might be a better way I am not aware of though

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer guided some additional searching which led me to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19850897/1646783 and between that answer and the information in your edit I separated the beans and that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem.
I am using Spring 4. I have no xml configuration.
Everything is configured with annotations and Java config.

I have a base configuration and a WebConfiguration.
the error was caused by using @ComponentScan in both configurations.
I removed component scan from base configuration.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myservice" })
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Bean
  public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
  }

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myservice" })  
@PropertySource("${myservice.properties.location:classpath:myservice.properties}")
public class BaseConfiguration  {


  @Autowired
  Environment environment;

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

solution : Quartz + Spring double execution java config

getServletConfigClasses()-> return null;

```
    public static class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};

    }
}
```

[example code solution](http://ideone.com/rr9L3G)