# Spring - @PostConstruct method called two times

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, annotations

Here is my Spring Controller class

```
@Controller
public class SchedularController{

  @Autowired
  ProjectRepository projectRepository;

  @Autowired
  UtilityRepository utilityRepository;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postconstruct(){
      System.out.println("Starting schedular...");
   }
}
```

Problem is when I start server postconstruct method runs two times.

I have checked another posts on this which mostly says - "That can happen if you have multiple frameworks managing the same bean class. E.g. JSF and CDI, or JSF and Spring, or CDI and Spring, etc."

But I am not using JSF or CDI and still having this problem.(and my @PostConstruct method is in controller class)

How to resolve this?

**Edit** -

Here is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>WBPPM</groupId>
 <artifactId>WBPPM</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <mongo-java-driver.version>3.0.2</mongo-java-driver.version>
    <spring-data-commons.version>1.7.2.RELEASE</spring-data-commons.version>
    <spring-data-mongodb.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</spring-data-mongodb.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring.version}</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Xstream and Json provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring / MongoDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${mongo-java-driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-mongodb.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tiles plugins -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.11</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- JSTL plugins -->
    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- java mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency> 
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Recaptcha check Api -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jasper Report -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- Freemarker Template -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- Excel File Read/write -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- amazonaws -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Push Notification -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.arcadiaconsulting.javapns</groupId>
        <artifactId>javapns</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-json</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.sauronsoftware.cron4j/cron4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.sauronsoftware.cron4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>cron4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies> 

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is my spring context file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.wb.ppm" />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**/*" />
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/*" />
        <bean class="com.wb.ppm.util.interceptor.WBInterceptor">
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.wb.ppm.util.logging.LoggingAspect" />
<bean id="applicationContext" class="com.wb.ppm.security.SpringApplicationContext"
    factory-method="getInstance" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="ApplicationResources" />
</bean>

<!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mongodb.properties"
    order="1" />

<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="${mongo.host.name}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mongo.host.port}" />
</bean>


<bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongo.db.name}" />
</bean>


<mongo:mapping-converter id="converter" />
<bean name="gridFsTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg ref="converter" />
</bean>

<bean id="userCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="${mongo.db.username}" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="${mongo.db.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- MongoConverter for converting the dot in map key to \+ in mongodb  -->
<bean id="mongoMoxydomainConverter" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="mapKeyDotReplacement" value="\\+"/>
</bean>


<!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and querying the documents in the database -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mongoMoxydomainConverter"/>
    <!-- <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="userCredentials" /> -->
</bean>

<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in 
    @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesviewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    <property name="order" value="2"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jstlviewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="3"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="xmlMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
</bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="150000000"/>
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="150000000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
</bean>
<bean id="simpleMappingExceptionResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="NotAuthorizedException" value="redirect:/login" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="redirect:/pages/error/globalError.jsp" />
</bean>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>WorldBankPPM</display-name>
<!-- Spring Listeners -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:worldbank-context.xml
        classpath:security-applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
    <param-value>src/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/worldbank-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>360</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/assets/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/vendor/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pages/error/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/pages/error/globalError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<!-- <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint> -->
```

Comment: Please post relevant logs excerpts along with config files

Comment: Add the object's `toString()` to the log output.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry I don't understand. What do you want me to do?

Comment: Let me guess you have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` both loading this xml file/

Comment: `System.out.println("Starting scheduler: " + this);` to see whether you're creating multiple objects.

Comment: @chrylis Yes multiple objects are being created. But why?

Comment: Just check http://stackoverflow.com/a/19850897/508957

Comment: @M.Deinum My `ContextLoaderListener` is `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` is `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Added my web.xml file

Comment: Both are loading that file means you are loading your whole application twice.

Comment: Okay then what should I do to prevent that?

Comment: Don't load them twice. Your contextloaderlistener should load the generic/global stuff (services, infrastructure, security etc.) the dispatcherservlet should only know and load controllers, view resolvers etc. all the web related stuff.

Comment: Please tell me how to limit `contextloaderlistener` to load only generic/global stuff?

Comment: Easiest solution is to use Spring Boot to handle all of your startup (optionally even including the container itself).

Comment: I solved this by removing `load-on-startup` tag from dispature-servlet.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem few days back and I have successfully solve this issue.

In my case I have created application using [Spring starter](https://start.spring.io/).

When you import project in Eclipse or any IDE you saw there is two classes in main package:

1. **ServletInitializer.java** which extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and overrides `configure()`, it gets called when we create **war** file and run under tomcat server
2. **YourApplication.java** contains `main()` which is entry point to our application if run/debug application on local server.

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908312/create-war-file-from-springboot-project-in-eclipse) to create war file and do necessary change.

Problem was I forgot to remove ServletInitializer.java which also contains the same method, this was the main cause of getting initialising twice.

Once you remove the extra code from that file, Spring Boot will only initialise your context once and will able to execute your code once.