# Create war file from Spring:boot project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, war

I am pretty new to Spring Boot and I have completed a application that works well on my localhost. As I have been told to deploy it outside my localhost on for example a webbhotel or simular I need to export the project as a war-file and not as a jar-file.

UPDATE!!
I run the project as a Springproject generated in Spring Initialzr and using Eclipse as a IDE.

In Eclipse I have followed the steps

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- … -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- … -->
</dependencies>
```

from Spring Boot Referencepage 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

In my project I use

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Do I need to add the sprinng-boot-starter-tomcat dependency and add provided to that on aswell as tomcat-embed-jasper so that my dependency will be like this?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to export to war-file in Eclipse, Eclipse can't find my project. It can find it if I try to export Java>JAR FILE but not if I try Web>WAR FILE

Do anyone know what I am doing wrong and if it is neccesary to export to a WAR-file to deploy to a external server?

Comment: Don't use the export JAR/WAR functionality from your IDE... Use maven to build your archive.

Comment: How do you export the project to WAR? Using `mvn package` or some other way? If you execute the Maven build, does it complete successfully?
 What do you end up seeing in the `target` folder after the Maven build is done?

Comment: i have tried the Eclipse export function, If I use the maven function, should I use both dependencies as I mention abouve or is it enough with tomcat-embed-jasper

Comment: I have no knowledge on programming spring and maven from cmd. I have used Spring intlzr to create the project and eclipse for the coding and testing. All has worked fine on localhost, the program run as it should. When I try to export the project the only alternative in Eclipse working is to export as jar-file. So I have not used maven build or maven package from cmd

Comment: Well, try it and see what you end up with, and come back if you have any issues. You'll have to learn Maven anyway, for any serious Java development. A word of advice: edit your original post for any updates/questions/new issues (or create a new question), instead of putting it into comments

Comment: Thanks, have updated the question. I am going to learn Maven but I don't have it at the moment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to extend ****SpringBootServletInitializer**** in your @SpringBootApplication

You don't need to add the ****sprinng-boot-starter-tomcat**** dependency for war file generation

[image]

Use below configuration in pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Configure Build Path for your project and select JDK

Right click on project > Run As > Maven Install

It will generate the war file inside target folder.

[image]

Copy this war and deploy to any web/application server (I have renamed it to demo.war).

You can access the app by using your host name followed by the port and app name.

[image]

Comment: SUPER!! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: The above steps all worked for me. But i added ojdbc8.jar as external jar at build path, It is not copied to lib folder of war file.So I am getting 'java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ' Exception. can any one help me here.

Comment: I have added ojdbc8.jar into tomcat9/lib folder. (tomcat9 is where tomcat was installed.) I do not know why but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Step1:- Create ServletInitializer file by extending SpringBootServletInitializer

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
}
}
```

Step2:- Use @SpringBootApplication in main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Step3:- Package type as war in pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Step4:- Give build filename as like this

```
<build>
 <finalName>demo</finalName>
</build>
```

Step5:- Add external tomcat dependency as provided scope

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Note:- For reference purpose, I'm adding my completed pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
 <finalName>demo</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate WAR file in STS (Spring Tools Suite):
Run as-> Maven Install

Comment: If you're going to recommend the Spring Tools Suite, you should start by suggesting the OP add it.  Further, as noted in the accepted answer, the packaging should be "war"; just running `mvn install` won't automatically produce a WAR without that being configured.

Answer (score 0):

After change to `<packaging>war</packaging>` in `pom.xml`.

utilize the command: `mvn package`

Answer (score 0):

You can also proceed by selecting menus `File -> Export -> Web -> War file`

Answer (score 0):

I generated a war file by the following steps:

1. Add above dependency.
2. Open command prompt.
3. `cd` into your project directory.
4. Run the command: `mvn clean install`.

Then a war file will be generated in the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you can add  tag to specify the type we want to create - jar or war. After that in sts you trigger a maven build  and specify the goals - clean install and specify the number of threads you want to run for the build. In case you want to skip the test case you can give skipTest =true, or if you to run from command prommpt you can give -Dmaven.test.skip=true.
Once done, war file will be generated under target folder. (unless we specify a specific deployment folder)