# Tomcat not redirecting to index.html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, tomcat

For some reason, my spring boot war which I have deployed into tomcat is not serving request for the site root from index.html. (index.html is at the context root).

When I use an executable war, everything works fine - https://domain.tld automatically loads index.html. For some reason when I deploy the same war to tomcat, and navigate to https://domain.tld, I get Spring Boot's 404 page. Going to https://domain.tld/index.html works fine, though. I see `"o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]"` in the startup log for both the executable war and tomcat's log. However, in tomcat's access log, there is a 404 and no redirect: `GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 286`

My web.xml has the following, which doesn't appear to be overridden anywhere. (Fresh tomcat install)

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Any ideas why there is different behavior, and how to fix it? I've been banging my head against this for most of the day with no luck.

## Update 1

Turned on trace logging and found the point of divergence, but have no idea what it means:

### Executable war (successful)

```
2020-09-23 01:34:21.348 TRACE 11076 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-23 01:34:21.353 TRACE 11076 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ParameterizableViewController [view="forward:index.html"]] and 3 interceptors
2020-09-23 01:34:21.362 TRACE 11076 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'forward:'
2020-09-23 01:34:21.362 TRACE 11076 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor'
```

### Tomcat (404)

```
2020-09-23 01:29:05.816 TRACE 10413 --- [apr-8443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-23 01:29:05.818 TRACE 10413 --- [apr-8443-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]] and 3 interceptors
2020-09-23 01:29:05.818 DEBUG 10413 --- [apr-8443-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2020-09-23 01:29:05.818 DEBUG 10413 --- [apr-8443-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2020-09-23 01:29:05.818 TRACE 10413 --- [apr-8443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2020-09-23 01:29:05.818 DEBUG 10413 --- [apr-8443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={masked}
```

Comment: Please check the link, it may help -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908312/create-war-file-from-springboot-project-in-eclipse/47912809#47912809

Comment: @NeerajBenjwal Didn't have anything relevant - that part of the process is working fine.

Comment: any update on this? @pepper any change you still know how you fixed that?

Comment: where is your `index.html` (relatively to your project structure/war)?

Comment: ...in `src/main/webapp` (maven-war-default) or in `src/mein/resources/static` (spring-boot-default)? I recommend the latter!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, when having `index.html` at the root of the WAR.

Spring Boot has indeed the ability to manage [welcome pages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.welcome-page).
But it will search `index.html` in configured locations.

These locations can be configured with the property [`spring.web.resources.static-locations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.web.resources.static-locations). Defaults to `[classpath:/META-INF/resources/, classpath:/resources/, classpath:/static/, classpath:/public/]`.

An old article (2013) from Spring Blog describing how to serve static content : [Serving Static Web Content with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot).

Also a guide to [Add a Home Page](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/#_add_a_home_page) in Spring Boot, with `index.html`.